# fill median of number in arrays

Tags: java, algorithm, math, data-structures, tree

We have array **arr** with n distinct elements. we want to fill `D[i]` be median of numbers `arr[1]` to `arr[i]`. it can done efficiently in `O(n log n)`.

Is there any effective way that we do this work?

Comment: If you already know that it can be done in  O(n log n) what is the question then? Do you expect an even more efficient way?

Comment: The Median is the ***"middle"*** of a sorted list of numbers *(ref: [MathsIsFun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/median.html))*. So sort the array and pick the middle value. Sorting is _O(n log n)_. --- For _O(n)_ solution, see e.g. [Selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) on Wikipedia.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** code / findings.

Comment: @Andreas we should fill the array D from index 0 to n for example D[0] contains meidan of elements array[0] to array[0]. D[1] contains meidan of elements array[0] to array[1].  D[2] contains meidan of elements array[0] to array[2]...

Comment: @MrSmith42 i want to understand logic. how we can reach to this time? what is the method?

Comment: @JohnatanMorian Your question is unclear. Are u looking for a O(nlogn) solution or a more optimal one?

Comment: You didn't explain what *D* is and how *n* is involved in the algorithm.

Comment: @SerialLazer both of them. at first I want to find this is lower bound? is there any more efficient version? if yes what? if no, how this lower bound can be reached (what is the algorithm)?

Comment: @akuzminykh D is another array, we want to fill this array with median of numbers in array a in such order that i descirbed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Theta(n log n)` complexity approach:

Make two heaps - maximal heap and minimal heap

Walk through array `a` and insert every element in two-heaps data structure.

If element is larger than currend median, add it to minimal heap (it contains larger elements), otherwise add it to maximal heap (with smaller elements)

Keep heaps of (almost) equal size (`(k+1)/2` and `k/2` at k-th step), moving top element into another heap if needed.

Median element of current slice is at the top of the larger heap

I hope it is enough to have these clues to implement.

[Java](https://ideone.com/rBjtoz) (I've had to learn a bit ;))

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{  Integer[] arr= {10,70,4,15,20,12,8,17};
   PriorityQueue<Integer>maxheap = new PriorityQueue<>(10, Collections.reverseOrder());
   PriorityQueue<Integer>minheap = new PriorityQueue<>(10);
   Integer median = -9999;
   for (Integer a: arr) {
      if (a >= median) {
         minheap.add(a);
         if (minheap.size() - maxheap.size() >= 2)
             maxheap.add(minheap.poll());
      }
        else {
         maxheap.add(a);
         if (maxheap.size() - minheap.size() >= 2)
             minheap.add(maxheap.poll());
        } 
        Integer diff = maxheap.size() - minheap.size();
        if (diff == 1)
             median = maxheap.peek();
        else if (diff == -1)
           median = minheap.peek();
        else   
            median = Math.min(minheap.peek(), maxheap.peek());
        System.out.println(median);
   }
}
```

Python implementation (first done). Minus is used to provide correct ordering of max heap (Python `heapq` is minimal heap) without additional comparator.

```
import heapq

arr=[10,70,4,15,20,12,8,17]
print(arr)
d = []
ds = []
minheap = []
maxheap = []
median = -99999
for i in range(len(arr)):
    sli = arr[:i+1]
    sli.sort()
    ds.append(sli[(len(sli) - 1)//2])

    if arr[i] >= median:
        heapq.heappush(minheap, arr[i])
        if len(minheap) - len(maxheap) >= 2:
           heapq.heappush(maxheap, -heapq.heappop(minheap))
    else:
        heapq.heappush(maxheap, -arr[i])
        if len(maxheap) - len(minheap) >= 2:
           heapq.heappush(minheap, -heapq.heappop(maxheap))

    diff = len(maxheap) - len(minheap)
    if diff == 1:
        median = -maxheap[0]
    elif diff == -1:
        median = minheap[0]
    else:
        median = min(minheap[0], -maxheap[0])
    d.append(median)

print(ds) #dumb method to compare
print(d)

>>>[10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 12, 12, 12]
>>>[10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 12, 12, 12]
```

Comment: A more in-depth explanation of that algorithm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15319593/4000124

Comment: my concerns is  about time complexity.  there is the lower bound am I right?

Comment: This approach provides `Theta(n log n)` complexity  (so complexity cannot be larger or (I think) smaller)

Comment: wow, where is wrong? suppose arr=[10,70,4,15,20,12,8,17]. we insert simultaneously  one by one in max and min heap. min heap root is 10, left be 70, up to yet median of two first element is root of mean heap. when 4 comes, root of mean heap change to 4 but median of first three element is 10 !!!! where am I wrong?

Comment: No, we insert elements into one heap (say maximal - note it contains smaller elements). When `maxheapsize - minheapsize >=2` occurs, we move top element of max heap into min heap (so size becomes equal).Top element of max heap is median. For your example max heap at the third step [10,4], min heap [70], median 10. After 8 steps maxheap [12,10,4,8], minheap [15,17,20,70].

Comment: @MBo thanks. a last tips: at step 3: max heap [10,4], min heap [70], at step 4: 15 comes to max heap -- > max heap [15, 4, 10] then difference with min heap be 2 then move 15 to min heap [15, 70] and max heap [10, 4] then we write median of max heap (10) in to D[i]. but at this step your algorithm move 15 to another heap before writing to array D. as we know final D=[10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 12, ...] and we have median 15 in D[i] but at this step we forward 15 to another heap before filling D ? would you please tell me how D[i] is fill in step 4 and 5 here?

Comment: In array of even length median might be chosen from A[n/2] and A[n/2+1]. If you want   - get top of another heap when length is even.

Comment: please clear comments so messy

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that array `arr` is already sorted in increasing order, the following code fills array `D`, where for each `i`, `D[i]` is the *median* of values `(arr[0], ..., arr[i])`.

```
// uncomment line below if arr is not sorted
// Arrays.sort(arr);

for (int i = 0, i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        
        // calculate median for array with odd length
        D[i] = arr[i/2];
    }
    else {
        
        // calculate median for array with even length
        D[i] = (arr[i/2] + arr[i/2 + 1]) / 2;
    }  
}
```

**Complexity:**
The time complexity for the above algorithm is O(n).

In case the initial array is not sorted and we have to sort it, this add time complexity O(nlogn). The final time complexity is *O(nlogn + n)* = *O(nlogn)*

Comment: a[i]'s are not sorted. Your solution wont work this way

Comment: is it possible to share your code to accept array online in order to test profaneness?